# Stray start tag label.HTML validation

Tags: html, validation

I tried to validate the code and receive the following error:

> Stray start tag label.

In all 3 label.

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-3 target-col desc-marketing" >
   <label >Targeted Lists</label>
   <div class="select-style" id="targeted-list">
    <select class="form-control">
      <option  id="sendToAll" value="1">
       <label for="sendToAll">Send To All Patients</label>          </option>
      <option  id="sendToAllLeads" value="2">↩
        <label for="sendToAllProspect">Send To All Prospects</label>
                             </option>

       <option  id="sendToAllLeads2" value="3">
        <label for="sendToAllLeads">Send To All Leads</label>
       </option>

     </select>
   </div>
   <span id="or">OR</span>
</div>
```

The origin of this error and how can I solve it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have labels inside an `<option>` tag. Place the `<label>` tag outside :

```
<label for="sendTo">Targeted Lists</label>
<div class="select-style" id="targeted-list">
    <select class="form-control" id="sendTo">
        <option  id="sendToAll" value="1">Send To All Patients</option>
        <option  id="sendToAllLeads" value="2">Send To All Prospects</option>
        <option  id="sendToAllLeads2" value="3">Send To All Leads</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

If you want to customise the look of your label, use a class on the option, that's all.

Comment: and what do you think I stink replace the label?

Comment: Place the label, you need one label for your select, not 3 for each of your options. I've edited my answer.